# Inheritance and pointers in Fortran

Tags: oop, pointers, inheritance, fortran

I have a type for linked lists in Fortran.  It is pretty useless, outside of demonstrating linked lists.  I hope to derive a type from it that I can put to some good use.  My base class is `link` and my derived class is `useful_link`.  `link` doesn't do much except create a new `link` and receives a pointer to that link.  My intent is that `useful_link` will create a new `useful_link` and also pass some useful data to its new creation.  (And, as you might guess, do a bunch of other stuff that I don't have time or space to discuss.)  My first pass at writing the code is:

```
    module links
      type link
        type(link), pointer :: child => null()
      contains
        procedure :: reproduce
      end type link
    contains
      subroutine reproduce(this, child_ptr)
        class(link) :: this
        class(link), pointer :: child_ptr
        allocate(this%child)
        child_ptr => this%child
      end subroutine reproduce 
    end module links

    module useful_links
      use links
      type, extends(link) :: useful_link
        real*8 :: dataval
      contains
        procedure :: reproduce_w_data
      end type useful_link
    contains
      subroutine reproduce_w_data(this, child_ptr, dataval)
        class(useful_link) :: this
        class(useful_link), pointer :: child_ptr
        call this%link%reproduce(child_ptr)   ! <--- problem!
        child_ptr%dataval = dataval
      end subroutine reproduce_w_data
    end module useful_links
```

This does not compile.  gfortran tells me "Error: Actual argument to ‘child_ptr’ ... must have the same declared type", and the problem is with the call to `reproduce` within the subroutine `reproduce_w_data`.  Also, if I re-write the code to remove the `child_ptr` arguments, and try to assign `dataval` to the new link with

```
this%child%dataval = dataval
```

then gfortran tell me "‘dataval’ ... is not a member of the ‘link’ structure".  Well, this all makes sense, but surely there is some way to make this work.  Anyone know what it is?

BTW, I have seen examples that use the `select type` construct, but that is horribly unwieldy and, if I understand it, I would have to add a new option to `reproduce` in the `link` type every time I added a new inheriting type, which seems to me to defeat one of the purposes of OOP.  Am I right about that?  I'm pretty new to OOP in Fortan.

Finally, could anyone recommend a good reference on this?  There seems to be many people out there who know this stuff well, but I can't find a place where it is all put together in one place.

Comment: I am not sure I see why those two classes should be linked by inheritance. You could make `child_ptr` `class(link)` and have a `select type` just in the extended procedure.

Comment: As a brief guide, I found this article helpful https://gist.github.com/n-s-k/de4af7ce6cc8f2c85e4b33cedb51fd88#4-case-study-data-polymorphic-linked-list

Comment: In subroutine `reproduce_w_data`, `this` has the extended type, so it inherits procedure `reproduce`. The call should be `this%reproduce(child_ptr)`.

Comment: @Aristotelis  Thanks, but sorry.  That change gives the same result.

Comment: @VladimirF  I think if I showed all that I am trying to do -- which I assure you, you don't want to take the time to read -- it would make more sense.  In reality, my linked list type does all the usual stuff that a linked list does and, if it ever works, the "useful_link" type will do many types of data processing, involving data from several different links simultaneously.  I want my new class to take advantage of all the stuff in the old.  I will take a look at your, suggestion, however.  Thanks.

Comment: Though not very sure, isn't the goal actually to create a generic linked list (like List<T> in other languages) rather than inheriting a linked list of a specific type (e.g. ListA -> ListAB)? In that case, I guess some template(-like) approach might be useful (for example, list in https://github.com/robertrueger/ftl )